# Apache Log : child pid 16619 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, joomla

I tried to setup my linux server [php7, mysql 5.6, Ubuntu 14 and Apache 2.4.20]  to host my joomla [v3.5.1] sites. But keep getting the following apache log everytime I run my joomla site and my website end with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

> [core:notice] [pid 16592] AH00051: child pid 16619 exit signal
>   Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

When I google the error, some people say endless loop of the function in PHP code can cause this error. But these joomla sites are fine in my local server.  Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: How much memory is there in the server?

Comment: do you mean physical memory? it is 4gb.